# Non-parametric test for unequal samples with subsequent post-hoc analysis?

Tags: spss, sample-size, post-hoc, small-sample, kruskal-wallis-test

Is it okay to perform a Kruskal-Wallis on four unequal samples? Further to this, is there a subsequent pair-wise post-hoc suitable for two unequal sample sizes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and Yes. Kruskal-Wallis analysis does not require equal sample size. In latest SPSS versions (from 18, if I remember correctly) there is a new nonparametrics procedure that performs pairwise comparisons with sig. adjustment, as well as step-down post-hoc method. Alternative would be to use very nice macro by Marta Garcia-Granero http://gjyp.nl/marta/

Comment: @ttnphs Thanks so much! What is the new procedure in SPSS then?

Comment: Starting from version 18 you may notice new nonparametric menus (= NPTESTS command) and legacy nonparametric menus (= NONPAR TESTS command) under Nonparametric Tests. The new menus are ugly but there is an option for post-hoc which was absent in NONPAR TESTS.

Answer (score 5):

According to the formula for the [Kruskal-Wallis test statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance), each group can have a different number of observations, so "yes".

Whether this is the best test or not I'm not sure - if you're still in doubt you'd need to post more details.  But perhaps this is all you needed to know.  Good luck!

Comment: Post-hoc analyses after this rely on "pair-wise" comparison, so are Mann-Whitney tests okay to look at where the significances are?

Answer (score 1):

In case of heavy unbalanced groups the Kruskal-Wallis-test may be far off and you **should not use it**. There is a recent paper published on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05650.pdf) by Brunner et al. 2018 "Ranks and Pseudo-Ranks - Paradoxical Results of Rank Tests" in which the authors show that under certain conditions Kruskal-Wallis-test for more than two groups with unequal sample sizes may lead to intransitive decisions and false rejection of the null hypothesis.

> This  means  that  for  the  same  set  of  distributions $F_1 ,..., F_d$ and unequal sample sizes the p-value of the test may be arbitrary small if $N$ is large enough.

A possible solution is provided by the concept of pseudo-ranks. Apparently, the authors have implemented solutions (which I have not tested yet) for this in R and SAS. See this reference for more information:

**Brunner, E., Bathke, A.C., and Konietschke, F. (2018).** *Rank- and Pseudo-Rank Procedures for Independent Observations in Factorial Designs - Using R and SAS.* Springer Series in Statistics, Springer, Heidelberg.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Mann-Whitney tests are the normal post-hoc test to use for a Kruskal-Wallis test.

Comment: No, Mann-Whitney are not the appropriate _post hoc_ tests following rejection of a Kruskal-Wallis test. Dunn's test is appropriate, see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25815/difference-between-post-hoc-test-after-kruskal-wallis-and-bonferroni-corrected-m/95270#95270.